# unable to assign array list to an array of an Object (Java)

Tags: java

So i am trying to make a deal or no deal game the game is not finished yet but the biggest issue i am having is that when i am trying to assign an array list to a array of type cases it seems like it isn't getting assigned.

I tried to debug and after shuffle the output is correct but i am unable to assign the result to the case array so that i can use it in game

Below are my 3 classes upon assigning the outcome i am getting is

[image: console output]

The line i am talking about is the method available cases

public class Case {

```
private int value = 0;
private String face;


/*
 * Constructor for type Case
 */

public Case(int value) 
{
    this.value = value;
}

/*
 * Getter and setter methods for instance data
 */

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String getFace() {
    return face;
}
public void setFace(String face) {
    this.face = face;
}
```

}

public class Player {

```
private String name;
private int age;
private boolean canPlay = false;
private int money = 0;

/*
 * Constructor for type Player
 */
public Player(String name, int age) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

/*
 * Getter and Setter methods for all instance Data
 */

public Player(boolean canPlay)
{
    this.canPlay = canPlay;
}

public int getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public void setMoney(int money) {
    this.money = money;
}

public boolean isCanPlay() {
    return canPlay;
}
public void setCanPlay(boolean canPlay) {
    this.canPlay = canPlay;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

/*
 * This method will check if the person playing is at least 18 years old or not
 */
public void checkAge()
{
    if(age >= 18)
    {
        canPlay = true;
        System.out.println("Seems like you are old enough to play!");
        System.out.println("Let's get started");
    }
    else
    {
        canPlay = false;
        System.out.println("OH NO! you aren't old enough sadly we won't be able to continue");
    }
}

public String toString() {
    return "Today's player is "+name+" who is "+age+" old";
}

public static void setupPlayer()throws InputMismatchException
{
    String playerName;
    int playerAge;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Deal or No Deal game!");
    System.out.println("Please state your name:");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    playerName = name.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Welcome "+playerName+" how old are you?");
    Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);
    playerAge = age.nextInt();

    Player gamePlayer = new Player(playerName, playerAge);
}

public static void Rules()
{
    System.out.println("Below listed are the Game Rules\n");
    System.out.println("-There are 12 Cases in the game");
    System.out.println("-Each case contains a amount of money and you will be "
            + "offered these Cases 1 at a time");
    System.out.println("-Upon picking a Case the game will end and you will have a "
            + "chance to walk away with that case");
    System.out.println("-If No cases are picked you will get 2 option, to walk away"
            + " with the last Case or take the bankers offer");
    System.out.println("-To accept the case type \"Y\" ,to decline it type \"N\"");
}
```

}

public class SetUpCases {

```
private  Case[] cases = new Case[12];

/*
 * This method initializes each object type with an amount which will be the Money in each Case
 */
public  void settingUpCases()
{
ArrayList<Integer> myCase= new ArrayList<Integer>();

myCase.add(new Integer(1));
myCase.add(new Integer(50));
myCase.add(new Integer(100));
myCase.add(new Integer(250));
myCase.add(new Integer(500));
myCase.add(new Integer(1000));
myCase.add(new Integer(2500));
myCase.add(new Integer(5000));
myCase.add(new Integer(10000));
myCase.add(new Integer(25000));
myCase.add(new Integer(50000));
myCase.add(new Integer(100000));

/*
 * The Shuffle changes which index has what value so game results are different each time played!
 */
Collections.shuffle(myCase);

for(int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++)
{
    int value = myCase.get(i);
    cases[i] = new Case (value);
    System.out.println(cases[i]);
}

}

/*
 * Shows which Cases are still available
 */
public  void availableCases()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < cases.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.println(cases[k]);
    }
}


public void startGame()
{
    settingUpCases();

}
```

}

Comment: *...  i am unable to assign the result to the case array ...* - Please clearly identify the specific line / lines you are talking about.

Comment: Edited the post now cheers

Comment: The output shows clearly that you HAVE assigned the `Case` objects to the array.   The problem is that you are printing them in a way that doesn't look nice.  Read the javadoc for `PrintWriter::println(Object)`.  That will explain what is happening, and should give you some ideas about how to make your code work.

Comment: The lesson here is that you need to figure out what the evidence *actually means* ... rather than jumping to conclusions, like "the assignment didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

You are printing case object instead of its value.. use `getValue` (or `getFace`) method to print the `value` (or `face`). For example

```
for (int k = 0; k < cases.length; k++)
{
    System.out.println(cases[k].getValue());
}
```

If you want to print both `value` and `face`, the best way will be to override the `toString` method and print these variables there.

Comment: Thanks a lot after changing my methods to static that fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting those weird values is not because the assignments aren't working but because you aren't printing the string value of your values.  Try the following.

```
for(int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++){
    int value = myCase.get(i);
    cases[i] = new Case (value);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cases[i]));
}
```

Comment: https://puu.sh/zT4oD/9330fdd16c.png I tried and it doesn't work the link shows the error